projection onto simplex after adding noise
Let $\Delta_K$ be the simplex of dimension $k$. Let $q \in \Delta_k$ be a fixed probability distribution. Let $Z \sim \text{Lap}(\lambda)^{\otimes k}$ where $\text{Lap}$ is the Laplace distribution.
Conisder the following two projections
\begin{align}
p_1 &\in \arg\min_{p \in \Delta_k} \| p - (q + Z) \|_1\\
p_2 &\in \arg\min_{p \in \Delta_k} \| p - (q + Z) \|_2.
\end{align}
Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^k$ be a fixed vector such that $\| a \|_\infty \leq 1$. I want to characterize
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\big| \langle\ p_1-q,a\rangle \big|\right]\quad , \quad \mathbb{E}\left[\big| \langle\ p_2-q,a\rangle \big|\right]
$$
In particular, I am interested in understanding how these two quantities scale with $k$.

Because $Z$ is i.i.d. $\text{Lap}(\lambda)$ in $k$ dimensions, we approximate $\langle p_i - q, a \rangle$ by examining how each projection trims $q+Z$ onto the simplex. For the $L_1$ projection, constraints shift the typical deviation scale to order $k\lambda$, whereas for the $L_2$ projection it stays around $\sqrt{k}\lambda$. Thus, the expected absolute dot product with $a$ (with $\|a\|_\infty \leq 1$) grows linearly in $k$ for $p_1$ and as $\sqrt{k}$ for $p_2$, up to universal constants. This reveals distinct $k$-scaling behaviors for the two projections.
